# how to add a new language for the user interface of opera browser

Tags: linux-mint, language, opera

I'm trying opera for the first time, it seems much faster than firefox but I'm unable to change the user interface language to my language.

I go to settings and press "Select user interface language" but I didn't find my language in the list.

I've seen the "preffered language" in settings and added my language and moved it up,I also tried adding a spell-checking dictionary for my language. However,  the menu is still english.

I tried a suggestion to move the lng file to /usr/share/langpacks and then open opera again, I didn't find langpacks but found help-langpack and language-tools and tried moving the file to the first, didn't work so I moved it to the second and didn't work either(and I don't think having the file copied in both directories will solve the problem).

Last thing I tried is creating /usr/share/langpacks and then moving the lng file to it, my language still doesn't appear in the list.
I downloaded an lng file but I didn't find any way to intall it.

so the question is : how to add a new language using the language pack I downloaded ?

### PS

I'm using linux mint 17.1 64bit cinnamon, my language is arabic and although the language pack seems to be for opera 12, I thought it might work on the latest stable version of opera which I currently use(which is 27)

Comment: Preferred language is the language for websites, not browser. What methods of installing that langpack have you tried?

Comment: @gronostaj the only thing I tried is in the post(after edit) as I didn't find anything regarding this issue

Comment: You could try to create `/usr/share/langpacks`, but the langpack probably won't work. Opera was rewritten from scratch between versions 14 and 15, so if that langpack is for Opera 12, then I doubt it will work. But you can try it anyway.

Comment: @gronostaj sorry, didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Languages from Opera 12 will not work in Opera 15+. Please post in the [Opera forums](http://forums.opera.com/) to request a new translations. You cannot easily supply new translations or resource files for newer versions of Opera.

Comment: where to post, I didn't find any subforum called "languages", do I just post it in Opera for *nix